# Maven dependency in multiple scopes

Tags: maven

I have a Spring project (Spring IO Brussels SR7) that is built using Maven 3.5.0.

The project depends on Java Mail API, which is declared as a provided dependency in my POM since it's going to be deployed on JBoss AS 7 server.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Version was omitted because dependencies are managed by the Spring IO platform. Version in Brussels SR7 is 1.5.6.

Running my test I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/PropUtil
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:982)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:65)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:160)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:127)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:155)
at com.mycompany.spring4base.web.controller.security.UserControllerTest.testFindUserFromActiveDirectory_Exists(UserControllerTest.java:441)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/PropUtil
    at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.<clinit>(InternetAddress.java:85)
    at com.mycompany.spring4base.model.security.User.getEmailAsInternetAddress(User.java:262)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:664)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:689)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:292)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1429)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:951)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:286)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:231)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.mail.util.PropUtil
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 64 more
```

Java Mail API is required for compilation and testing purposes.

Looking at my local .m2 repository, I can see that javax.mail-1.5.6.jar has the com.sun.mail.util.PropUtil class. Running mvn dependency:tree, I got this:

```
[INFO] com.mycompany.:spring4base:war:1.4.0-RELEASE
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.11.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.13.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core:jar:2.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.olap4j:olap4j:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.5:compile
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.51:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:6.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:jar:138:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:138:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.bouncycastle:bctsp-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.19:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:jar:4.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.castor:castor-xml:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.castor:castor-core:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:4.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:4.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:4.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:4.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:jar:4.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- jakarta-regexp:jakarta-regexp:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.zxing:core:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:57.1:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.12.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:provided
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:provided
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.12.Final:provided
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.6.Final:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp:javax.servlet.jsp-api:jar:2.3.2-b02:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api:jar:1.2.1:provided
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] +- javax.mail:javax.mail-api:jar:1.5.6:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- javax.el:javax.el-api:jar:2.2.5:test
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.web:javax.el:jar:2.2.4:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.5.1:test
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:jar:1.3:test
```

My question is: How should I setup my Maven POM for this to work as expected?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two jars involved here:

- javax.mail-1.5.6.jar with Maven coordinates com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.5.6
- javax.mail-api-1.5.6.jar with Maven coordinates javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.5.6

The first jar contains the class that is missing in your test (and this is the file that you checked in your .m2-repo). The second jar is the one that you have included in your pom. Try to add the first jar as additional dependency.

Comment: You nailed it. Thank you!